# os.chmod() is Python 2.7 only works for file?

Tags: python-2.7, chmod

It seems os.chmod(path, stat.S_IWSUR) only works for file. Is it a known bug? How can I chmod for a whole folder including its content?

Answer (score 0):

`os.chmod` is not intended to replicate all features of the `chmod` shell command; it's more like the [`chmod` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html). Particularly, like the system call and unlike the shell command, it doesn't support a recursive chmod; you'd have to do that yourself with something like [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

You *can* `os.chmod` a directory, but it won't chmod the directory's contents.